# Property 'keys' does not exist on type 'any[]'

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2017

Next example in VS2017 reported error: Property 'keys' does not exist on type 'any []'

```
[].keys()
```

Why error?

Version of Visual Studio 2017  - 15.6.4

Version of TypeScript tools - 15.6.20202.3

Version of TypeScript - 2.8

Comment: seems to work fine in the playground https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=%5B%5D.keys()%3B

Comment: @toskv Thanks! Question updated. Error in Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem fixed after tsconfig.json changing.

tsconfig.json

```
"compilerOptions": {
  ..
  "lib":["es2015"]
  ..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"esnext" works for me when used in tsconfig.json. Using VS Code